# ASP.NET Web API 2, how to distinguish methods with similar url

Tags: c#, asp.net

My team are using ASP.NET Web API framework.
In our application, we have 2 method which look like this:

```
[Route("users/events"]
[HttpGet]
public UserEvent GetEventsAssociatedWithUser(string Id) { ... }
```

and

```
[Route("users/{Id}"]
[HttpGet]
public User GetUserInformation(string Id) { ... }
```

but whenever I want to send request to "...users/events", it keeps send it to "...users/{Id}" and use "events" as an URI parameter.

I just want to know if there is any way to solve this problems without changing the URL of any of these method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a route order like this

`[Route("users/events", RouteOrder = 1)]`

Read more here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#order

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `RouteOrder` parameter
See here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#order

Example:

```
[Route("users/events" RouteOrder = 1]
[HttpGet]
public UserEvent GetEventsAssociatedWithUser(string Id) { ... }
```